# What is the distribution of a constant divided by a uniform distribution?

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution

Say I have a uniform distribution $P \sim \text{Unif}[1,2]$ and a constant $m$.

If I divide $m$ by $P$, will I still have a uniform distribution such that$\frac{m}{P} \sim \text{Unif}[\frac{m}{2}, m]$?

I am asking this question as it seems deeply intuitive that since P takes on a value equally likely from 1 to 2, that taking a constant over P would equally give an equal distribution but now around the new support.

Thank you!

Comment: It is impossible. Try a computer simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We let $P\sim $ Unif$[1,2]$. Then one can calculate that $Y:=1/P$ has the following density function:

$$f_Y(y)=\begin{cases}\dfrac1{y^2},&y\in[1/2,1]\\0,&\text{else.}\end{cases}$$

So $Y$, or $m/P$, is not uniformly distributed. The random variable $m/P$ does take values in between $m/2$ and $m$.

Comment: Not worth its own separate answer, but in general the inverse of a probability distribution is not just the same probability distribution applied to the inverses. The distribution described here is referred to as the [Inverse uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Inverse_uniform_distribution)

Comment: Nevertheless, it is a very nice addition! Good reference.

Comment: Thank you so much Mark! :)